# can't find python packages installed into customized docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am creating a Docker container that runs Python 3.6.15 and the pip install function in my Dockerfile runs during the build process but when I try to execute functions within it after the build completes and I run it the 'installed' packages do not exist.

For more context, here is my Dockerfile. For clarity, I am building a Docker container that is being uploaded to AWS ECR to be used in a Lambda function but I don't think that's entirely relevant to this question (good for context though):

```
# Define function directory
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM python:3.6 as build-image

# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  g++ \
  make \
  cmake \
  unzip \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  ffmpeg

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy function code
COPY . ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install the runtime interface client
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install \
        --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
        awslambdaric

# Install the runtime interface client
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Multi-stage build: grab a fresh copy of the base image
FROM python:3.6

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy in the build image dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

COPY entry-point.sh /entry_script.sh
ADD aws-lambda-rie /usr/local/bin/aws-lambda-rie
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entry_script.sh" ]

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

When I run my `docker run` command in Terminal, I can see that it is collecting and installing the packages from the requirements.txt file that is in my project's root. I then try to run an get an Import Module error. To troubleshoot, I ran some command line `exec` functions such as:

```
docker exec <container-id> bash -c "ls"  # This returns the folder structure which looks great

docker exec <container-id> bash -c "pip freeze". # This only returns 'pip', 'wheel' and some other basic Python modules
```

The only why I could solve it is that after I build and run it, I run this command:

```
docker exec <container-id> bash -c "/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

Which manually installs the modules and they then show up in the `freeze` command and I can execute the code. This is not ideal as I would like to have `pip install` run correctly during the build process so there are less steps in the future as I make changes to the code.

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong would be great, thank you!

Comment: what is the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable at container runtime? is the --target directory in there?

Comment: I was using /usr/local/bin/python since that's what is returned when I run `which python` within the container. The value of `sys.path` is:  `['', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`. I wonder if I should explicitly run it with that Python version (even though I'm guessing the main python command is just an alias of it...)

Comment: Different variables.  The pythonpath tells python where to find the libaries. The path tells the command shell where to find binaries.

Comment: Ok, yeah, using the `/usr/local/bin/python` command installs in that site-packages directory from sys.path so it seems like it should be working fine when I run the `docker build` command...

Comment: Earlier I had wondered if the 2nd `from python:3.6`  wiped that out.  I see you have a copy for `/function` to persist that directory's content to the 2nd stage, but thats only the AWS module.

Comment: Basically, either your modules are there and python cant find them, or they were deleted -- possibly by the 2nd from.

Comment: Ok yes, I'm going to test by placing the pip install statement closer to the end (after the second FROM statement).

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/   confirms that it blows away prior artifacts...

Comment: That was it, I just confirmed. Thank you! If you want to add as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Docker n00b over here...

Comment: I think multiple `from` in a Dockerfile are confusing.  I guess I prefer the `&&` and `\\` to chain commands into fewer RUN statements.

Comment: @Paul thanks. This script I'm using was based off a template that AWS provides (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). I agree with you, seems much cleaner to do it your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Docker Docs, multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

> With multi-stage builds, you use multiple FROM statements in your
> Dockerfile. Each FROM instruction can use a different base, and each
> of them begins a new stage of the build. You can selectively copy
> artifacts from one stage to another, leaving behind everything you
> don’t want in the final image.

So the 2nd `from python:3.6` in the Dockerfile resets the image build, deleting the module installations.

The subsequent copy saves what was in `/function` (the aws module) but not the other modules saved to the system in the other pip install.